# how to merge two 3d-arrays on the 2nd dimension efficiently?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, numpy, merge

Lets say I have two 3 dimensional arrays (a & b) of shape (1.000.000, ???, 50), (??? = see below).

How to merge them,
so that the result will be (1.000.000, {shape of a's + b's second dimension} , 50)?

Here are the samples, as you can see below: (np.arrays are also possible)

EDIT: added usable code, please scroll^^

```
[ #a
     [           
                 ],
     [ 
       [1  2  3]
                 ],
     [ 
       [0  2    7]
       [1  Nan  3]
                 ],
     [ 
       [10   0  3]
       [NaN  9  9]
       [10 NaN  3]
                 ],
     [ 
       [8  2  0]
       [2  2  3]
       [8  1  3]
       [1  2  3]
                 ],
     [ 
       [0  2  3]
       [1  2  9]
       [1  2  3]
       [1  0  3]
       [1  2  3]
                 ]
                     ] 



[#b
     [ 
       [7  2  3]
       [1  2  9]
       [1  2  3]
       [8  0  3]
       [1  7  3]
                 ]
     [ 
       [3  9  0]
       [2  2  3]
       [8  1  3]
       [0  2  3]
                 ],
     [ 
       [10   0  3]
       [0  NaN  9]
       [10 NaN  3]
                 ],
     [ 
       [0  2  NaN]
       [1  Nan  3]
                 ],
     [ 
       [1  2  NaN]
                 ],
     [           
                 ]
                     ] 

a = [    [                ],
     [ [1, 2, 3]          ],
     [ [0, 2, 7],  [1,np.nan,3]   ],
     [ 
       [10,0,3],  [np.nan,9,9],  [10,np.nan,3]
                 ],
     [ 
       [8,2,0],  [2,2,3],  [8,1,3],  [1,2,3]
                 ],
     [   
      [0,2,3],  [1,2,9],  [1,2,3],  [1,0,3],     [1,2,3]    
                 ]
                     ] 
 
b = [
     [ 
       [7,2,3],     [1,2,9],   [1,2,3],  [8,0,3],   [1,7,3]
                   ],
     [ 
       [3,9,0],   [2,2,3],   [8,1,3],   [0,2,3]
                   ],
     [ 
       [10,0,3],  [0,np.nan,9],   [10,np.nan,3]
                   ],
     [ 
       [0,2,np.nan],  [1,np.nan,3]
                   ],
     [ 
       [1,2,np.nan]
                   ],
     [           
                   ]
                     ]
```

expected outcome:

```
[ 
     [ [7  2  3]# from b
       [1  2  9]# from b
       [1  2  3]# from b
       [8  0  3]# from b
       [1  7  3]# from b
                  ],
     [ 
       [1  2  3]
       [3  9  0]# from b
       [2  2  3]# from b
       [8  1  3]# from b
       [0  2  3]# from b
                 ],
     [ 
       [0  2    7]
       [1  Nan  3]
       [10   0  3]# from b
       [0  NaN  9]# from b
       [10 NaN  3]# from b
                 ],
     [ 
       [10   0  3]
       [NaN  9  9]
       [10 NaN  3]
       [0  2  NaN]# from b
       [1  Nan  3]# from b
                    ],
     [ 
       [8  2  0]
       [2  2  3]
       [8  1  3]
       [1  2  3]
       [1  2  NaN]# from b
                 ],
     [ 
       [0  2  3]
       [1  2  9]
       [1  2  3]
       [1  0  3]
       [1  2  3]
                 ] 
                     ]
```

Do you know a way to do that efficiently?

EDIT: tried concatenate (didnt work):

```
DF_LEN, COL_LEN, cols = 20,5,['A', 'B']
a = np.asarray(pd.DataFrame(1, index=range(DF_LEN), columns=cols))
a = list((map(lambda i: a[:i], range(1,a.shape[0]+1))))
  
b = np.asarray(pd.DataFrame(np.nan, index=range(DF_LEN), columns=cols))
b = list((map(lambda i: b[:i], range(1,b.shape[0]+1))))
b = b[::-1]

a_first = a[0];  del a[0]
b_last  = b[-1]; del b[-1]
result  = np.concatenate([a, b], axis=1)

>>>AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1
```

Comment: can you format the arrays to be valid code?

Comment: @anon01 edited it^^ thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have an array with variable length in a dimension. `a` and `b` are most likely list of lists and not arrays. You can use list comprehension along with zip:

```
np.array([x+y for x,y in zip(a,b)])
```

**EDIT**: or based on comment provided if `a` and `b` are lists of arrays:

```
np.array([np.vstack((x,y)) for x,y in zip(a,b)])
```

The output for your example looks like:

```
[[[ 7.  2.  3.]
  [ 1.  2.  9.]
  [ 1.  2.  3.]
  [ 8.  0.  3.]
  [ 1.  7.  3.]]

 [[ 1.  2.  3.]
  [ 3.  9.  0.]
  [ 2.  2.  3.]
  [ 8.  1.  3.]
  [ 0.  2.  3.]]

 [[ 0.  2.  7.]
  [ 1. nan  3.]
  [10.  0.  3.]
  [ 0. nan  9.]
  [10. nan  3.]]

 [[10.  0.  3.]
  [nan  9.  9.]
  [10. nan  3.]
  [ 0.  2. nan]
  [ 1. nan  3.]]

 [[ 8.  2.  0.]
  [ 2.  2.  3.]
  [ 8.  1.  3.]
  [ 1.  2.  3.]
  [ 1.  2. nan]]

 [[ 0.  2.  3.]
  [ 1.  2.  9.]
  [ 1.  2.  3.]
  [ 1.  0.  3.]
  [ 1.  2.  3.]]]
```

Comment: Code tried this:    (reproducable)

DF_LEN, COL_LEN, cols = 20, 5, ['A', 'B']

a = np.asarray(pd.DataFrame(1, index=range(DF_LEN), columns=cols))
a = list((map(lambda i: a[:i], range(1,a.shape[0]+1))))
  
b = np.asarray(pd.DataFrame(np.nan, index=range(DF_LEN), columns=cols))
b = list((map(lambda i: b[:i], range(1,b.shape[0]+1))))
b = b[::-1]

a_first = a[0];  del a[0]
b_last  = b[-1]; del b[-1]

print(len(a), len(b))
for x,y in  zip(a,b):
    print("x = ",x)
    print("y = ",y)
    
result = np.array([x+y for x,y in zip(a,b)])

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: please check the new edit on the post I added based on your code. I ran and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

To perform your concatenation, run:

```
result = np.concatenate([a, b], axis=1)
```

To test this code, I created *a* and *b* as:

```
a = np.stack([ np.full((2, 3), i) for i in range(1, 6)], axis=1)
b = np.stack([ np.full((2, 3), i + 10) for i in range(1, 4)], axis=1)
```

So they contain:

```
array([[[1, 1, 1],        array([[[11, 11, 11],
        [2, 2, 2],                [12, 12, 12],
        [3, 3, 3],                [13, 13, 13]],
        [4, 4, 4],        
        [5, 5, 5]],              [[11, 11, 11],
                                  [12, 12, 12],
       [[1, 1, 1],                [13, 13, 13]]])
        [2, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 3],
        [4, 4, 4],
        [5, 5, 5]]])
```

and their shapes are: *(2, 5, 3)* and *(2, 3, 3)*

The result of my concatenation is:

```
array([[[ 1,  1,  1],
        [ 2,  2,  2],
        [ 3,  3,  3],
        [ 4,  4,  4],
        [ 5,  5,  5],
        [11, 11, 11],
        [12, 12, 12],
        [13, 13, 13]],

       [[ 1,  1,  1],
        [ 2,  2,  2],
        [ 3,  3,  3],
        [ 4,  4,  4],
        [ 5,  5,  5],
        [11, 11, 11],
        [12, 12, 12],
        [13, 13, 13]]])
```

and the shape is *(2, 8, 3)*, just as it should be.

## Edit following the comment as of 19:56Z

I tried the code from your comment.
After you executed `a = list((map(lambda i: a[:i], range(1,a.shape[0]+1))))`,
the result is:

```
[array([[1, 1]], dtype=int64),
 array([[1, 1],
        [1, 1]], dtype=int64),
 array([[1, 1],
        [1, 1],
        [1, 1]], dtype=int64),
 array([[1, 1],
        [1, 1],
        [1, 1],
        [1, 1]], dtype=int64),
 array([[1, 1],
        [1, 1],
        [1, 1],
        [1, 1],
        [1, 1]], dtype=int64),
...
```

so *a* is a **list** of arrays of varying sizes.

Theres is something wrong in the way you construct your data.
First check that your both arrays are *3-D* and their shapes differ
only in axis 1. Only then you can run my code on them.
For now both *a* and *b* are plain *pythonic* **lists**, not *Numpy* arrays!

Comment: Your answer gives insight but your `a` and `b` structure is different than the examples provided in the question by OP.

Comment: tried it, but it doesnt work with the incrementing amount of rows... Here is a reproducable sample:

Comment: @Ehsan
tried it, but it doesnt work with the incrementing amount of rows... Here is a reproducable sample:
DF_LEN, COL_LEN, cols = 20,5,['A', 'B']
a = np.asarray(pd.DataFrame(1, index=range(DF_LEN), columns=cols))
a = list((map(lambda i: a[:i], range(1,a.shape[0]+1))))
  
b = np.asarray(pd.DataFrame(np.nan, index=range(DF_LEN), columns=cols))
b = list((map(lambda i: b[:i], range(1,b.shape[0]+1))))
b = b[::-1]

a_first = a[0];  del a[0]
b_last  = b[-1]; del b[-1]
result  = np.concatenate([a, b], axis=1)  >>> 
AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1

Comment: thanks for your edit. somehow I cant convert these subsublists into arrays
tried:
a  = np.array([np.asarray([np.asarray(x) for x in slice_]) for slice_ in a])
b = np.array([np.asarray([np.asarray(x) for x in slice_]) for slice_ in b])